# Json response only current data

Tags: php, json

This is my query and all thing going very well. problem is that only json response. when I print json .its showing only one data .while I want to list all data of current user .so please if any help then let me know Thanks .
 $user1 = $wpdb->get_results(
        "select product,checked_by,submit_date from diary_user_form_storage where DATE(submit_date) = CURDATE() ;
    ");

```
foreach ($user1 as $key => $value) {
    $productString = stripslashes($value->product);
    $checked = stripslashes($value->checked_by);
    $checked_by = json_decode($checked , true);
    $product = json_decode($productString, true);
    $checked_by = json_decode($checked , true);
    $product = json_decode($productString, true);
     $date=$value->submit_date;
    $date1 = date('Y-m-d',strtotime($date));
    $timing= date('H:i:s',strtotime($date));
    $jsonString = "";
}
 header('Content-type: text/json');
echo json_encode(
            array(
                "status" => "1",
                'user_id' =>  $user->ID,
                                'message' => 'fetched',
                "token" => $token,      
                'token' => $token.$device_id.$device_type,
                'serverUrl' => $serverUrl,  
     'option'=>$option,
     'product' => $product,
     'checked_by' =>$checked_by ,
     'submit_date'=>$timing 
    ));
?>
```

Comment: Can you please, provide actual output and expected output.

Comment: Your foreach loop is overwriting values during each pass.  Add them to an array inside your loop, then return the full array once the loop is finished

Comment: EaetPeanutButter@hey can you implement your solution, I tried many time but its not succeeded,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You misunderstand what a [foreach loop](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php) is, and may be confused about [variable scoping](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php). Each time the loop loops over an element of your query, this line is executed:

```
$productString = stripslashes($value->product);
```

which overwrites the same variable over and over again. So, in the end, when you `echo json_encode(/*stuff*/)` only the content of the last iteration of the loop gets outputted.

Luckily for you, you can just put the echo in the loop, and each part will be outputted by your script.

**Make sure to put the header before that, or your script will fail.** Headers (`header('Content-type: text/json');`) need to be sent before actual content.